# How to copy text including special characters to clipboard using C and WinAPI?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm trying to make little c program that copies text to clipboard. I found this question asked on this website. Programs code:

```
const char* output = "Test";
const size_t len = strlen(output) + 1;
HGLOBAL hMem =  GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len);
memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), output, len);
GlobalUnlock(hMem);
OpenClipboard(0);
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
CloseClipboard();
```

This program does copy text to clipboard. But i need it to copy 2 lines. So i try this:

```
const char* output = "Test1\nTest2";
```

But it gets copied as literal. How can i fix this code so result would be:

```
Test1
Test2
```

rather then:

```
Test1\nTest2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page for [Standard Clipboard Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729168(v=vs.85).aspx) says this about `CF_TEXT`:

> Text format. **Each line ends with a carriage return/linefeed (CR-LF)
>   combination**. A null character signals the end of the data. Use this
>   format for ANSI text.

So you probably need:

```
const char* output = "Test1\r\nTest2";
                           ^^
```